# How to get a symbolic answer

Tags: maple

I am coding some optimization problem in Maple, and actually I did something and got a numerical solution. Right now I want to do the same thing but need to get the symbolic answer. The problem I have is to compute the compose of a given convex function $f$ with a linear map, sequare Matrix A say, and to do that, I have to compute $(f\circ A)(y)= \{f(\phi): \phi=A^{-1}.y\}$. So what I did is that I made a procedure to do this computation in Maple but for a giving particular vector $y$. Now as far as the matrix $A$ is invertible, I want to compute $(f\circ A)(y)= \{f(\phi): \phi=A^{-1}.y\}$ and to get a symbolic solution (function) not a specific solution. For example in one dimension, let

[image]

and the matrix $A=[5]$ then

[image]

for any vector $y$ in the range of A. Can anyone help me for coding this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not about math, but about coding something in Maple. You would get a quicker answer at Mapleprimes.com